# Kibana map not showing tooltip

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I have a sample index named 'geolocation' with the below schema -

```
{
    "storeid": "32308",
    "name": "My sample store",
    "salesvolume": 1000.00,
    "location": {
        "lat": 47.2419,
        "lon": -122.46645
    }
}
```

And my index properties are as below -

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "storeid": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "salesvolumes": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to plot a map with the above data with Kibana and show a tooltip displaying the name and sales volume for each location.
I have created a map using Add layer-> Documents -> selecting the above index.The locations are plotted on the map but I don't see any tooltip once I hover on any location. How can I configure tooltip for each location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing the layer, you have a section called "Tooltip fields", that's where you can add fields to show up in tooltips when hovering over the location.

[image]